# Mysql TIMEANDDATE changing when importing table to server

Tags: mysql

somwthing super weird is happening hope you can help me. I have a local mysql running and my data for example is like this:

```
Product - Price - Time
Microphone - 10 -  2021-06-14 08:44:17
```

Time is the time this information was parsed from the website.

So now I dump this table with the command:
mysqldump -u root -p Mydatabase Mytable > C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Mytable.sql

After that I export this to the server (bluehost) with:
mysql -h  -u  -p  < C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Mytable.sql

The weird thing is that the time and date when uploading to server automatically changes to something else and does not stay the same as in the original data collected in the local mysql !!!

Do you understand what is potentially happening?

Thanks

Comment: What does it change toäo? Does only the hour change, in that case it may be because of different server timezones.

Comment: The problem is that when I throw it into a datatable and put it in a website people think that the last time I updated the prices was a while ago (maybe server time) but it fact the price was updated just now and I want people to see the correct time/date when it was updated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, yes that was a server issue. At bluehost I had to find .htaccess file and add the line "php_value date.timezone "America/Denver." under the